# How to get TEXT (not value) of an input of type "number"

Tags: javascript, html

With an input of type number, how to get the TEXT displayed on the input (not the value) when the value is invalid.

Exemple :

```
<form>
   <input type="number" id="num" step="any">
</form>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Outlivier/pen/bvqXvg)

If the user enter the invalid value "0..1" (instead of "0.1"), `document.getElementById('num').value` return an empty string.
How to get with JavaScript the text "0..1" ?

**Why this question ?**

The goal is to provide better validation message. The input of type number is "tricky" and the behavior inconsistent, if the user enter " 5" in Firefox, it's an invalid number, I want to be able to display in my validation message why the number is invalid.

Comment: If you're validating it with JavaScript, the easiest way would be to set an input type text and to check then with js only...

Comment: I found method `window.num.reportValidity()` and `.checkValidity()`. it return false in case of invalid value, and true otherwise.

Comment: @Logar : Ok it's the same question, i should have search with the term "raw value", thanks.